# ERROR: Call to a member function getProducts() on a non-object

Tags: php, opencart

I am getting an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getProducts() on a non-object
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/designsense.net.au/gypsy/public_html/catalog/controller/module/cart.php
>   on line 23

This is the code i am using.

```
    class ControllerModuleCart extends Controller { 
    protected function index() {
    $this->language->load('module/cart');

    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');
    $this->data['text_subtotal'] = $this->language->get('text_subtotal');
    $this->data['text_empty'] = $this->language->get('text_empty');
    $this->data['text_remove'] = $this->language->get('text_remove');
    $this->data['text_confirm'] = $this->language->get('text_confirm');
    $this->data['text_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_cart');
    $this->data['text_checkout'] = $this->language->get('text_checkout');
    $this->data['button_checkout'] = $this->language->get('button_checkout');
    $this->data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');
    $this->data['text_cart'] = $this->language->get('text_cart');

    $this->data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart');
    $this->data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', 'SSL');

    // Get Cart Products
    $this->data['products'] = array();

    foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $result) {

        $option_data = array();

        foreach ($result['option'] as $option) {
            $option_data[] = array(
                'name'  => $option['name'],
                'value' => (strlen($option['option_value']) > 20 ? substr($option['option_value'], 0, 20) . '..' : $option['option_value'])
            );
        }
```

Any suggestions on what could be causing this?

Comment: could this be related? $this->data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart'); ....... $this->cart->getProducts()

Comment: is $this->cart defined?

Comment: @SpongePablo how do i check to see if it is? I didn't write the code, so im not too sure.

Comment: Framework?? codeigniter?

Comment: @mongjong is this  $this->data['cart'] = $this->url->link('checkout/cart'); defining it?

Comment: Nope $this->data['cart'] doesn't isn't the same as creating the object $this->cart.  You're missing code somewhere which creates the $this->cart element as an object which means you can't use its methods until it is created.  Usually it'll be something like $this->cart = new cart() or something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Try to load the model before you call the function getProducts()

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant use `$this->cart->getProducts();` in `foreach` loop.

So that you need to assign value to variable

`$products = $this->cart->getProducts();`

This little line of code is most important in that it makes a call to the function `getProducts` which is a core procedure located in `system/library/cart.php`. The variable `$products` now has the entire cart array + all possible options and can be “iterated” through. To iterate means to sift through an array, gathering it’s contents or to LOOP through. Let’s take a look at what is happening in the f`unction getProducts();` In `system/library/cart.php` find this function towards the top:
then use this in `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($products as $product) 
{ 
  //your code here
}
```

This code is the `foreach(`) loop set up to go through the array we just set up in `system/library/cart.php`. It is responsible for displaying all of the content seen in the shopping cart page along with the product options. Everything below `foreach ($products as $product) {` will repeat itself as many times as necessary until ALL PRODUCTS HAVE BEEN DEALT WITH IN THE ARRAY.

This will work fine.

Read this [Article as well](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=144&t=91436)

**EDIT 01**

```
public function getProducts()
{
    if ( !$this->data )
    {
        foreach ( $this->session->data['cart'] as $key => $quantity )
        {
            $product = explode(':', $key);
            $product_id = $product[0];
            $stock = true;// Options
            if ( isset($product[1]) )
            {
                $options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
            }
            else
            {
                $options = array();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that, now the new error is:
Fatal error: Call to a member function getProducts() on a non-object in /var/www/xxxxx/public_html/catalog/controller/module/cart.php on line 19

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProducts() on a non-object in /var/www/xxxxx/public_html/catalog/controller/module/cart.php on line 19

Comment: @Fushy Check **EDIT 01**

Comment: I have tried adding that, but then all of the variables below that comes up as undefined. I have added that code on line 2, (same code as above). Unfortunately the error i get is way to long to post in a comment.

Comment: check the link i have posted in my answer

Comment: I have, but its the same as the stuff you posted. I might have to rewrite all of the code to look similar to the code in the link. Thanks for the advice

Comment: i have managed to get that to work, but i still get the same error i originally got? as i understood it, the getProduct function would have defined the $products?